# How can i get scheduled jobs from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I want to know how I can get scheduled jobs for lets say 2 days from now on. From Jenkins API.

I have nearly hundred jobs scheduled, I am having hard time tracking them. I would love a easy check on which of them are going to run tomorrow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schedule Jenkins job using Jenkins Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186314/schedule-jenkins-job-using-jenkins-rest-api)

Comment: No, i am not looking for how to schedule a job. I have bunch of jobs that are already scheduled. I need to find out which of them are scheduled to run tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This groovy script should help you : [DisplayCronTiggersInViewDescription](https://github.com/codecentric/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/src/main/groovy/DisplayCronTiggersInViewDescription.groovy).

Look for  TimerTrigger (or SCMTrigger)

Personally, I would just run as a standalone groovy script or from console and forget updating the view. You also may want to look for SCMTrigger (ie Poll SCM).

This script will let you [manipulate](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/trigger-manipulator.groovy) them too.

There are similar answers within s/o if you look.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use this to print out scheduled jobs:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.triggers.*

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { Job job ->
  for(trigger in job.triggers.values()) {
    if(trigger instanceof TimerTrigger) {
        output = sprintf("%-30s %-30s", trigger.spec.trim().replace("\n", ", "), job.name.trim())
        println(output)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to track future jobs, give a try with [Calendar View](https://plugins.jenkins.io/calendar-view/) - allows you to have a month, week and day view of past jobs (and their results) as well for the future jobs.

Comment: This plugin is awesome, it helps us to plan all scheduled jobs and predicts the execution time based on previous builds